# How to share custom swift extensions I built and find really useful

Tags: ios, swift, github, open-source, swift-extensions

I'd like to share some really useful swift extensions that I built for my apps. I'm sure there are many developers that are looking to easily add the custom functionality to their apps. The only issue is I can't find a good way to share these extensions.

I'm a experienced software engineer(most of my experience is web related) that started working iOS apps recently and I'm not familiar with packaging and distribution of swift extensions.

I'm currently using Carthage as a dependency manager and I know CocoaPods is more popular and maybe Swift Package Manager will be something in the near future - so I'd like to be able to publish the extensions so people using any of these package managers can easily add them to their projects.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Either share them on CocoaPods or put them up on your own website. I'm sure people will find out about them if they are useful either way :)

Comment: I was thinking about making a blog post on my (soon-to-be-public) blog, and putting everything on github also. How I see it users should be able to use them with a simple copy/paste. From what I've read so far it seems the simplest way of sharing them, but I wonder if people would prefer to manage them using a dependency manager

Comment: I think most people would be fine with both, but the advantage of CocoaPods is you can easily update to new versions and install - that may be better :)

Comment: Yeah - it's like set and forget, and the maintainer handles any breaking code changes. I think I'll do both - blog post + cocoapods + carthage. I'm just not clear if I need to make a xcode project with 1 file containing the extension or I can have only the .swift file where the extension is defined and just add the dependency manager stuff

Comment: The swift file should be in the extension, but a full project should also be provided: I'll explain more in my answer below

Comment: it would be great if you can guide a bit - thanks!

Comment: Here you are :) Take a look at the answer

Comment: I will - just waiting for more suggestions from other users - I'll select the best answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would recommend using a dependency manager like CocoaPods in order to make updating to newer versions of your extensions and installing them easier.

You may also want to share a link to the CocoaPods pods on your personal blog and spread the news about your libraries/extensions.

> In CocoaPods you should provide the .Swift file as the installable pod, but should also provide the Xcode project for **pod try** functionality, where people try out your extension before embedding it into their projects.

Here is an example of a transition extension on CocoaPods (these are the files shown in GitHub):

[image]

> As you can see, a demo project is provided, but when installing the pod, only the relevant Swift files are added to the project.

Here's where you can get started: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

Hope that clears things up. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

So you mentioned CocoaPods, this would be my preferred way of distributing your extensions. You'll need to package them into a Framework (or leave them as source, if you want your project to be open-source). Then you'll need to upload the framework/source files to a GitHub repository (as CocoaPods is essentially a layer on top of GitHub). Then create a `podspec` file according to these guidelines: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html At that link you can also find instructions for releasing your pod after you have satisfied the prerequisites.

Comment: I plan to share them full source. From what I can tell so far I need to create a new Xcode project, add the extension file as the single file of the project, and share that on github -> and after that check each package manager on how to support it. Am I getting this right ?

Comment: Yes, make sure your new project is a library project rather than an app. Also make sure to mark all your objects, methods and variables public as by default swift uses internal access control. (If you don't do this, and I learned the hard way, none of your exposed methods/variables will be accessable.)